# Set from address based on sender to address

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I've got a number of email addresses forwarding to my gmail. I've also set up in my gmail so that I can select my "from" address to be these email address which forward to gmail. However, sometimes I forget, and people get confused when they receive an email from my personal address.

Is there a way to set up my "from" address to default to the "to" address of the email I'm replying to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have gmail "Reply from the same address the message was sent to"

- Open gmail settings using the gear /settings
- click Accounts and Import
- In the "Send mail as:" section click the radio button "Reply from the same address the message was sent to"

Comment: Wow, that was easy, can't believe I missed that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great tip. Only catch is, this doesn't work when the address you used to receive the message is on a mailing list (or in a Google "Group"), it appears only applies to addresses that are in the "To" header.